# Does the US Consumer Law entitle buyers to refunds for future price reductions?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection

I have heard that if I buy something in a store, and that price is reduced within a week or so, I am entitled to get the difference. Is that true?

Edit:
Here is an example from Apple:

> Should Apple reduce its price on any Apple-branded product within 14 calendar days from the date you receive your product, feel free to visit an Apple Retail Store or contact the Apple Contact Center at 1-800-676-2775 to request a refund or credit of the difference between the price you were charged and the current selling price. To receive the refund or credit you must contact Apple within 14 calendar days of the price change. Please note that this excludes limited-time price reductions, such as those that occur during special sales events, such as Black Friday or Cyber Monday.

From: http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/sales-policies/retail_us.html

Comment: The example you show is a *voluntary* policy of the retailer.  It is not mandated by law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. But fortunately when you buy something, the store also can't come after you for more money if the price goes up.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the price provisions like the ones that you quote arise from the companies as a matter of policy that they believe will encourage buyers to buy now instead of later. Contract law makes those agreements enforceable.

But, most consumer protection laws in the United States are adopted at the state level and they vary wildly from state to state.

For example, Colorado makes it a deceptive trade practice to advertise goods for sale at a very low price but then to only make a very small number of units of that good available for sale. There is, in effect, a statutory right to a "rain check" in Colorado. But, most other states would not have that consumer protection right.